# Validate a list of xml files

Tags: grep, xml, xmllint

I'd like to validate a list of xml files against a schema, and only be notified of failures.

This command seems to work, but the last grep command has no effect:

```
find -iname "*.xml" | xargs xmllint --schema PersonDetails.xsd | grep -F "fails to validate"
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

The text is actually coming out of stderr. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout) technique to grep the stderr text.

For example:

```
find -iname "*.xml" | xargs xmllint --schema PersonDetails.xsd 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -F "fails to validate"
```